# How we can process the Store and Forward Using JMS Message Stores

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

i have done all the changes in axis2 file and drop the jar files in lib
my message process is working fine and storing also
when ever i am sending request to proxy which consist store mediator and defined target.endpoint also after request message storing in message store its not processing 
my configure files

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Message" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="faisal" value="faisal" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="target.endpoint" value="JmsChecking" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <store messageStore="faisal5"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy
```

and message store is

```
<messageStore name="faisal5" class="org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.destination">faisal5_Queue</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

and message processor

```
<messageProcessor name="faisal" class="org.apache.synapse.message.processors.forward.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" messageStore="faisal5" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">4</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

and endpoint define which is like this 
and its entries

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JmsChecking">
   <address uri="http://localhost:8282/services/JmscheckingEndpoint" format="soap11">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

end point consist log values proxy

```
proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JmscheckingEndpoint" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Message" value="JMs working fine"/>
            <property name="value" expression="//mail/text()"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Now i am sending my request 
this log value is printing like this

```
[2013-07-25 11:42:03,039]  INFO - LogMediator Message = JMs working fine, value = faisal.shaik@youtility.in
[2013-07-25 11:42:03,039]  INFO - LogMediator Message = JMs working fine, value = faisal.shaik@youtility.in
[2013-07-25 11:42:03,039]  INFO - LogMediator Message = JMs working fine, value = faisal.shaik@youtility.in
[2013-07-25 11:42:03,039]  INFO - LogMediator Message = JMs working fine, value = faisal.shaik@youtility.in
```

as well as message process is deactivating .if i am send one more request its just storing its not processing bcoz of message process is deactivate state
this JMS work only like this
MY scenario is i will get request if endpoint is available message will deliver and delete as well if endpoint is unavailable message will retry max mention times even also endpoint not available then it will store in message store
what is the use of this parameter will you please explain about this 
i followed this link http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores 
where can i found this faisal5_Queue store point is it exist as folder

```
   <parameter name="store.jms.destination">faisal5_Queue</parameter>
```

Answer (score 1):

No it does not create a folder. when you mention the "store.jms.destination" using 
faisal5_Queue wso2 esb will create an queue in your message broker(In your case ActiveMQ) with your specified name "faisal5_Queue". If you did not mention explicitly, WSO2 esb will create an queue with "YourMessageStoreName_Queue"

you can refer furthermore on these blogs to understand the behaviour of "Message Store" and "Message Processor"

http://vanjikumaran.blogspot.com/2013/08/jms-store-and-jms-processor-behavior.html
http://vanjikumaran.blogspot.com/2013/08/jms-messagenstore-and-jms-message.html
http://vanjikumaran.blogspot.com/2013/08/jms-messagen-store-and-jms-message.html